# How to add validation to a form

Tags: php

I would like to validate a form so that it checks if the user is logged in...

I have got a form with method and action given below:

```
<form method=get action="index.php">
```

What I would like to do is that when I click on proceed to checkout, this form should validate if user is logged in. If not it will redirect to login page. I am hoping to put my php code inn the form so that user do not proceed to checkout unless he is logged in.

I tried to use onclick"if (($_SESSION['user_name']) == "")" then it should redirect to login.php.

Comment: @Petah: How exactly is that a rubbish question? Just because it seems obvious to you, doesn't mean it is to him!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. PHP code is used on the server side, you can't use it on the client side `onclick=""` attribute.

You need to **submit the form**, and then on the page which handles the request, **check if the user is logged in, and if not redirect**.

Comment: Thanks...It worked but i had to put exit(1) so that it does not have to display the next instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the active user data in a session variable and then check if that user session exists.

-> user **starts** a session by successfully completing your authorization process.

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;

?>
```

-> check active user function

```
<?php

 function check_active_user() {

   if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {   
     return true; 
   } else {   
     return false; 
  }
}

?>
```

-> check if active user = true;

```
<?php

  if (check_active_user()) {
    echo 'session active';
  } else {
    echo 'session not active';
  }

?>
```